# First step in statistics: something-like-a-mode for a sequence where each value is different from another

Tags: statistics

Sorry but I'm not a statics expert at all, but I'm following some on line course and it is fascinating me.

I just found the existence of the mode:

> The mode is the value that appears most often in a set of data. (Wikipedia)

What about a sequence where the values are different one from each other? Like

```
l = [1, 1.2, 1.3, 0.9, 12, 5]
```

I'd like to take out from this sequence a value that is not the average (that is 3.5) because it is not explicative enough so I thought to discretize (like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 5]`) them and then take the mode (that would be 1) but I'm sure that there is a better way.

Comment: is there a tag for say "basic concept"?

Comment: Split the data to chunks.  How we do it is has no real rules, say $0$ to $2$, $2$ to $4$, $4$ to $6$, and so on. Mode is $1$ (midway point serving as identifier). Not very persuasive, we have hardly any data. For say $100$ data points, the analogous procedure begins to be reasonable. Mode is really not important, though bimodality can be (clusterings around **two** values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no uniquely Right Way to define the concept that you're grasping at, but you're not alone in wanting to do so. The (ill-defined) problem you're trying to solve is called [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), and there's an entire field of research dedicated to it.